# Command line args accepting -SS also where as expected is -S using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have command line argument `-S` as defined below

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        '-S',
        '--save',
        action='store_true',
        help='Save to directory'
    )
```

but if I use -SS instead of -S, python doesn't throw any error. I want invalid argument error. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `'--S'` in place of `'-S'`

Comment: @Pygirl, I already have `--save`. Please check edited version of the question.

Comment: If your `action` was a counter, you'd see the effect of using `S` twice.  With `store_true` it just sets the value to `True` twice.

Comment: @hpaulj But I don't need counter action. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `allow_abbrev=False` in `argparse.ArgumentParse`

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
parser.add_argument('-S',action='store_true',help='Save to directory')
parser.parse_args()
```

Output:

```
user@localhost:/tmp$ python3 temp.py -S
user@localhost:/tmp$ python3 temp.py -SS
usage: temp.py [-h] [-S]
temp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -SS
```

Error is raised when it is called with `-SS`

Comment: 3.9 was corrected to apply the abbreviation test only to double dash strings.

Comment: There's fairly recent bug/issue on this, but I don't recall how well it's documented.  The first introduction of `allow_abbrev` broke  the long standing use of chained short options, `-vv`, `-bv` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Single Dash`.
Use `Double Dash`. Because In single Dash(takes one single character),
when you do `-SS` it is equivalent to `-S -S` that's why no error.

But if you use Double Dash then it will be

```
--SS => --SS
```